# 'gtk/gtk.h' file not found Mac

Tags: macos, gtk

I'm trying to run my projet ut it makes me this error when I run it

fatal error: 'gtk/gtk.h' file not found

include < gtk/gtk.h >

1 error generated.

(I already install gtk+ and gtk3+)
Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome Binocloo. This question is too imprecise to be answered. You say too little about your compiler, environment, way you installed GTK+, which version exactly, etc. You should read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add missing information so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I got a cpp to build by including the right header path when compiling as shown in this thread: ['gtk/gtk.h' file not found, make error on mac #23](https://github.com/deiv/driftnet/issues/23).

```
-I/usr/include/gtk-2.0
```

To me, it was a bit different since I had installed gtk+ via homebrew. So I did:

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+/2.24.32_2/include/gtk-2.0/
```

I hope this helps.